# Rackspce Compressed (zipped) folders error

Tags: ios, zip, unzip, rackspace

I am not sure what's the problem is but I try to explain. My customer has [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/email-hosting/) email server. I use smtp to send my email to this server with attached zip file from my iOS application.

For sending email via smtp I use [SKPSMTPMessage](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage) by Ian Baird.

For creating zip file I use [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive).

So everything works good and I have not got any issues. Zip archive was created and email was send.

Rackspace server forward this email to an gmail account. When I download zip from the gmail, it has not got any issues. But when my customer tried to download zip directly from Rackspace it caused an compressed (zipped) folders error:

[image]

But on my Mac I can check this zip in the Document directory of iOS app and I can unzip it without any problem. Even if Rackspace forwards emails to gmail, everything goes good with this zip and when I download zip from gmail it works, but downloading from Rackspace causes this issue that I've attached on image.

If I understood right this is not my issue, and maybe zip file was being truncated during download from Rackspace, I don't know what the problem is because I don't have access to Rackspace to check what's really happened there.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try opening the downloaded file in a text editor. Sometimes Right Click &rarr; Save Link As... does not work because the target relies on a scripted redirect before actually sending the file, so what gets saved is the intermediate page instead of the intended file. The text editor makes this case obvious. You should also check the size of the file on disk to see if it's something much smaller than the expected size.

Comment: @280Z28, thank you for comment. ok one more I don't have direct access just know about this problem as I described, So I as I understood we need to open zip in text editor. And we open it we can resave it? But how can this solve my issue? Sorry I do not understand the peculiarities of Rackspace

Comment: No, I'm saying they might not have downloaded the file at all. For example, Right Click the following link and select Save Link As..., then open the result in a text editor: https://github.com/antlr/website-antlr4/blob/gh-pages/download/antlr-4.2-complete.jar